# Find lowest integer in list, which has both strings and integers

Tags: python

I want to find the lowest integer in a list, which contains strings and integers. Is there a quick way to find it?

I could solve the issue with regex. But that sounds too much work for this. 
Create a new list, with list comprehension sounds better. But isn't there an easier way?

```
my_list = [2, 4, 'foo']
```

of course `min(my_list)` won't work because of the string inside.

Comment: "I could solve the issue with regex. But that sounds too much work for this"- Arie Osdorp (2019) - 
Read enoguh in StackOverflow

Comment: on Python 2 you can just do `min(my_list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generator expression to filter out non-ints:

```
min(n for n in my_list if isinstance(n, int))
# returns 2
```